# Como usar múltiplos $_GET em PHP através de uma URL

Tags: php, html, get

Através de uma URL, desejo exibir um conjunto de informações no HTML da página, no entanto, há valores que desejo repetir em certas URL's e em outras não.

Exemplo:

http://wwww.example.com/example.php?c=resultado1

```
<?php echo "<div class='campo1'>" . $_GET['c'] . "</div>" ;?>
```

Eu quero repetir o `$_GET['c']` na URL, e automaticamente gerar uma nova DIV com o novo valor passado pela URL

http://wwww.example.com/example.php?c=resultado1&c2=resultado2

O que não estou conseguindo é acertar o PHP no HTML. Eu tentei duplicar a função `echo` acima, mas caso eu não informe o valor do GET dela na URL, a DIV é exibida mesmo assim (em branco), algo que não quero que aconteça. Como devo proceder?

Answer (score 2):

Basta fazeres uma condição com o uso da função [isset](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) que verifica se a variável está definida e é não nula.

```
if(isset($_GET['c']))
    echo "<div class='campo1'>" . $_GET['c'] . "</div>" ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Você deve fazer o seguinte:

```
<?php 
    echo isset($_GET['c']) ? "<div class='campo1'>" . $_GET['c'] . "</div>" : ""; 
?>
```

ou

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['c'])){
       echo  "<div class='campo1'>" . $_GET['c'] . "</div>"; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: Lembrando que o [isset](http://php.net/isset) não valida se a variável está vazia, somente se ela existe. Então se o parâmetro via $_GET vier e estiver vazio, o isset retornará true.

Answer (score 1):

Há também uma maneira de ocultar a div pelo CSS quando a mesma está vazia.

Basta utilizar

```
<style>
#campo1:empty{
  display:none;
}
</style>
```

Só gostaria de chamar atenção para os cuidados que se deve ter ao exibir conteúdos vindo de dados de usuário.

Pois o código abaixo deixa seu código vulnerável a injeções de xss (Cross-site scripting):

```
<?php 
    echo isset($_GET['c']) ? "<div class='campo1'>" . $_GET['c'] . "</div>" : ""; 
?>
```

Se isso realmente vai para produção (e não for somente um teste, para fins de estudos), recomendo que faça da seguinte forma

```
<?php 
  echo isset($_GET['c']) ? "<div class='campo1'>" . htmlentities($_GET['c']) . "</div>" : ""; 
?>
```

pois assim você evita que alguém digite um javascript na url e injete códigos na sua página.